# Extended event (sp_statement_completed) firing multiple times

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, extended-events

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 enterprise and this is my first foray into extended events. It's pretty cool stuff. I'm wanting to create a session that will run basically all the time to audit query times on our SQL Server. I will then be able to pipe that data into a product called Splunk and correlate that data with all sorts of other metrics.

Anyway, I'm having some odd things happen (odd to me ... I'm sure there is a reason) with the sp_statement_completed event. The .xel file is growing SUPER fast ... like 1GB in a minute fast. Looking at the data I see the same SQL statements duplicated sometimes 75-100 times. What can I do to deduplicate/filter this data prior to going into the file? Many of them have a cpu of zero and duration of zero. I think I might even be seeing a little duplication using `sql_statement_completed`. I've also noticed that I do see stored procedure end times using the `sql_statement_completed` event. So, is there even a need to use `sp_statement_completed`?

Any thoughts would be most welcomed and thanks in advance.

Comment: You might benefit from reading the following articles from Joe Sack's: [Observer overhead – the perils of too much tracing](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/joe/observer-overhead-the-perils-of-too-much-tracing/) and [Observer Overhead and Wait Type Symptoms](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/07/sql-trace/observer-overhead-and-waits). Extended events and server side traces are great, but sometimes cause unexpected issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue is because my stored procedures and ad hoc queries might be running more than one sql statement ... thus creating multiple hits. Really what I need is batch complete. Alas, it does not exist in SQL Server 2008. Probably gonna have to resort to a server trace.